# Prediction approach using JS (for MEAN Stack app)

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mean-stack

I have a collection of car objects in my MongoDB database and my record format is below:

```
{
    "Name": "toyota corolla 1600 (sw)",
    "Miles_per_Gallon": 27,
    "Cylinders": 4,
    "Displacement": 97,
    "Horsepower": 88,
    "Weight_in_lbs": 2100,
    "Acceleration": 16.5,
    "Year": "1972-01-01",
    "Origin": "Japan"
    }
```

I have a form which asks users some questions about their lifestyle and preferences and then the application suggests the car from the database. I am using AngularJS, NodeJS and MongoDB. I have only 4 questions that I ask in the form.

I have searched through the web and found that I have to use clustering or desicion tree to do it.

**Now I am interested in the clustering algorithm that I have to choose. Or should I use desicion trees? I am not that proficient in JS. Could you please suggest me the easiest way to do it?**

Any hint or help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and properly format your postings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't predict with clustering.

You need a **supervised** approach and quality **training data** (many users for each car *with* their "lifestyle" - like Amazon). It won't be easy. You can't give meaningful recommendations just from a database of old cars (and why would you recommend a 1972 car anyway?)

Comment: Sorry for late answer, It is just a practise project and i have four questions. For example the first question is "Family and Lifestyle". In other words if the user selects "small family,I commute to and from work" i choose the cars with 4 cylinders for him/her.

Comment: That is a hard-coded if-then rule. No learning involved. You won't be able to use machine learning unless you have *thousands* of training data points (of preferences, not of cars. You'll likely need 10-100x as many preferences than you have cars).